# Trouble with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
import os
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="test")

def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.forward_message(chat_id=ADMIN_CHAT_ID, from_chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="test")
    ADMIN_CHAT_ID = os.environ.get('1014171853')

def main():
    TOKEN = os.environ.get('<MY-TOKEN>')
    ADMIN_CHAT_ID = os.environ.get('228')

    token= "<MY-TOKEN>"
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    echo_handler = MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, echo)

    dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
    dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
 File "c:\Users\rufer\OneDrive\desktop\codes\bot2.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\rufer\OneDrive\desktop\codes\bot2.py", line 17, in main
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
```

I tried to specify the token as a variable when i get this error, but I still don't understand how to fix this error. My version of python-telegram-bot is 20.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check the site resources like [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current question is lacking a lot of critical information and it makes it very difficult to help you.

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.

Comment: What error? Please see [ask]. Using the python-telegram-bot examples, please state what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is written for version <=13.x of `python-telegram-bot`, but as you've stated yourself you've installed version 20.2, which is incompatible. Please check out the [documentation of `python-telegram-bot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org) to see up-to-date examples.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.